# How to sample from a list of items with associated value according to a specific value proportion distribution?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, sampling

I have a list of items (40799 in total) and each comes with a value. It looks like the following -

| item_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 88563 |
| id2 | 85154 |
| id3 | 81726 |
| id4 | 79855 |
| id5 | 72417 |

I need to sample from this list of items, and select 24 unique item_id such that each item_id's value/(cumulative sum of value of 24 selected items) approximately match a known list of proportion values (p1, p2, p3,..., p24) where p1 + p2 + p3... + p24 = 1.

How should I conduct this sampling in Python?

Thanks!

I tried looking into probability proportional sampling but it doesn't seem to be what I need for this problem.

Stratified sampling was suggested but not sure how this could be accomplished since we do not have subgroups defined for this population.

Comment: Do you need an optimal solution or a reasonable solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that's quick and practical, but I can't promise any statistical properties other than the target distribution, i.e., some values may be more sampled than others.

Roughly, the idea is this:

1. Pick a random element from the very large array.
2. Multiply that element by ratios of the p<sub>x</sub> values, then look up the first value greater than that target in the large array. (Here, also, some work can be done, closest would likely be better).
3. Assign the particular value of p<sub>x</sub> to your random element that minimizes squared error vs the intended distribution and return the resulting values.

The whole thing is quite fast as we can use `np.searchsorted` to find the first element greater than or equal to a target value.  To put this into production, you'd need to add some additional bookkeeping to go between sorted and unsorted values. However, you consistently get samples that match your target distribution.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
very_big_arr = np.random.choice(100000, 79855)
proportions = (item := np.random.uniform(0, 1, 24)) / item.sum()
proportions.sort()

ratio_set = np.array([proportions/proportions[i] for i in range(len(proportions))])
sorted_big_arr = very_big_arr.copy()
sorted_big_arr.sort()



def find_closest(selected_elem):
    vals = np.zeros(ratio_set.shape)
    spots = np.zeros(ratio_set.shape, dtype=int)

    for test_row, row in enumerate(ratio_set * selected_elem):
        spot = 0
        for position, elem in enumerate(row):
            spots[test_row, position] = np.searchsorted(sorted_big_arr[spot:-len(row)+position], elem) + spot
            vals[test_row, position] = sorted_big_arr[spots[test_row, position]]
            spot = spots[test_row, position]
    diff_from_props = (vals / vals.sum(axis=0)) - proportions
    min_row = (diff_from_props * diff_from_props).sum(axis=0).argmin()
    return vals[min_row], spots[min_row]



vals, spots = find_closest(np.random.choice(very_big_arr))
print(vals)
print("Sample (%):")
print(vals / vals.sum() * 100)
print("Target (%):")
print(proportions * 100)
```

Yields:

```
[ 1075.  1780.  2879.  3141.  7043.  8716.  9148.  9462.  9464. 11960.
 12106. 14240. 14432. 15117. 15204. 16751. 17180. 17975. 18387. 18740.
 19816. 20372. 20578. 21067.]
Sample (%):
[0.35058197 0.58049851 0.93890742 1.02435159 2.29688259 2.84248597
 2.983371   3.08577355 3.08642579 3.9004282  3.94804212 4.64398809
 4.70660366 4.92999775 4.95837043 5.46288234 5.602789   5.8620566
 5.99641917 6.11154051 6.46244859 6.64377285 6.71095414 6.87042817]
Target (%):
[0.35024601 0.58044595 0.93877093 1.0243262  2.2969562  2.84197991
 2.983598   3.08494687 3.08669238 3.90074419 3.94790199 4.6433762
 4.70661593 4.93022893 4.95836253 5.4634611  5.60332495 5.86220951
 5.99687634 6.11067393 6.46227882 6.64420291 6.71100396 6.87077624]
```